# Facebook "like" dialog box (XFBML) overflows normal page boundary, how to flip it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The dialog that pops up after a user clicks "like" on my (in development) website overflows the main content area of my website:

[image: Facebook like dialog overflow]

Is there any way to flip it around so that it pops up to the left of the like button instead of to the right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same issue here, it sucks! did you find a resolution?

Comment: afraid not, I redesigned the page it was on :-/

Comment: Facebook button just sucks balls, no matter how you tune it. The google +1 though, comes much more flexible right from the stock...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this is not possible. Even if there are hacks for this, it won't be legal.

You just need to keep it the way it is, or change its place.

Comment: This is incredibly disappointing! Are you completely certain?

Comment: Well, yeah! Won't harm if a Facebook employee confirms this...anyone?